# Determining the equation of a line given angle with x-axis and other area related conditions

Tags: integration, functions, area

[image]

In the above figure, $f(x) = \frac {1}{x}$ and $g(x)=ax+b$,  $A$ is the area in unit squared between the x-axis, $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and the line representing $x=1$ in the first quadrant . $\alpha$ is the angle between the positive x-axis and $g(x)$. If $\alpha= 60^{∘} $ and $A=1$, find $a$ and $b$.I have tried using the fact that $\tan {60°}=\sqrt 3$ to find the slope of the equation and finding $a$. It is finding $b$ which is turning out to be troublesome. Other things I have tried are writing an expression in $b$ using the area of a triangle and the antiderivative of $\frac {1}{x}$ being $\ln x$ . Edit- This question was posted earlier but was poorly written and so didn't gain much attention. I apologise for that and hence I have edited it and reposted

Comment: A few things - unless there is more info, there are two solutions when line $g(x)$ is left of $x = 1$ and when it is to the right of it. Also, finding $b$ is not straightforward. I had to take help of WolframAlpha. Also I am assuming $\alpha$ is angle with positive x-axis.

Comment: @MathLover I edited the question to include the info that $A$ is in the first quadrant.

Comment: @MathLover Please do share your method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If line $g(x)$ makes $60^0$ angle with positive direction of the x-axis (which should be more clearly mentioned in the question otherwise there are additional solutions), there are two possibilities - either $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ as well as $g(x)$ and x-axis intersect to the left of $x = 1$ OR both to the right of $x = 1$. I will show a working for the intersection points to the right of $x = 1$. You can do similarly if the line was to the left but then the solution for $A = 1$ takes the part of the area to the second quadrant so can be discarded. But you can do the working and validate.

Also note that there is another possibility that the line intersects the curve to the right of $x = 1$ but x-axis to the left of it. The way question reads, it is most likely not to be considered as then there is no single region bound  between x-axis, $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $x = 1$.

If $f(x) = \cfrac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=ax+b$ intersect at $ \left(x_0, \cfrac{1}{x_0}\right)$,

Area under the graph $f(x)$ between $1 \leq x \leq x_0$ is $ \ A_1 = \ln (x_0)$. This area also includes area of the triangle to the right of $g(x)$ between x-axis, $g(x)$ and $x = x_0$ which should be subtracted.

As angle with x-axis is $60^0$, $g(x) = \sqrt3 \ x + b$.

So, $\cfrac{1}{x_0} = \sqrt3 \ x_0 + b \implies b = \cfrac{1}{x_0} - \sqrt3 \ x_0$

At intersection of $g(x)$ and x-axis, $x = - \cfrac{b}{\sqrt3} = x_0 - \cfrac{1}{\sqrt3 \ x_0}$

So area between x-axis, $g(x)$ and line $x = x_0$

$ \displaystyle A_2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(x_0 - \left(x_0 - \frac{1}{\sqrt3 \ x_0} \right) \right) \cdot \frac{1}{x_0}$

$ = \cfrac{1}{2\sqrt3 \ x_0^2}$

Now $A = A_1 - A_2 = 1$

$\implies \ln (x_0) - \cfrac{1}{2 \sqrt3 \ x_0^2} = 1$

I used WolframAlpha to solve for $x_0 \approx 2.8189 $

So, $b \approx - 4.53$